# How to create buttons for each element in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, let's say I have a dictionary:

```
var objects = {
  "one" : ["1", "2"],
  "two" : ["4", "6"],
  "three" : ["3", "5", "7"]
};
```

And I am first going to take some input, and depending on the input (from `"one"`, `"two"`, or `"three"`), and use the dictionary to get an array, and use the values inside the array to create buttons for each of them. Then, the buttons are going to lead onto other functions.

Here is the function I have written so far:

```
function func1(choice){
  for (var key in objects[choice]) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode(key);
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.onclick = func2(key);
    var div = document.getElementById("example");
    div.appendChild(button);
  }  
}
```

Instead, no new buttons are showing up. How do I fix this?

Comment: You forgot to append the created button anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I appended it, but accidentally left it out of this post. I will edit it.

Comment: where is func2 ? should go like button.onclick = function(){}

Comment: `button.onclick = func2(key);` <-- This is calling `func2` right away and whatever the return value from it is, that's what you are making the callback function of the `onclick` property. If you meant that `func2` should be called as the callback function, it should be: `button.onclick = function() {func2(key);}`